# Database design: lots of rows vs lots of tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm doing this database design stuff for a system where i need to store some variable length arrays into mysql database.

The length of the arrays will be (at most) in hundreds if not thousands.

New arrays will be created on a regular basis, maybe tens daily.

1. should I store these arrays into one table that will soon grow gigantic or
2. create a new table for each array and soon have a huge number or tables?
3. something else? (like formatted text column for the array values)

to clarify, 1. means roughly

```
CREATE TABLE array (id INT, valuetype VARCHAR(64), ...)
CREATE TABLE arr_values (id INT, val DOUBLE, FK array_id)
```

and 2.

```
CREATE TABLE array (id INT, valuetype VARCHAR(64),...)
CREATE TABLE arr_values (id int, val DOUBLE, FK array_id) -- template table
CREATE TABLE arr1_values LIKE arr_values ...
```

The arr_values will be used as arrays that is queried by joining to a complete array.
Any ideas on why some approach is better than other?

Comment: 10 records per day isn't very much, that is only 3,750 records per year, I have an application that gets around 1,000 new records per day to a single large and complex table, the total new records is around 1,200 per day to this application in all tables. Remember that it is not unusual for a mySQL DB to have millions of rows. Due to the variable nature of the data you have, have you thought about if your application could work better with a DB like mongoDB that has no set schema? It is an object oriented DB but may be worth a look depending on what your application does.

Comment: 10 would be an underestimate but let's say 80 new arrays per day that contain say 3000 values on average. That would make more than 11 million rows each year. Or about 3750 tables with 3000 rows on average.

Comment: 11 million is large but still manageable, if this app is to be used long-term do think about scalability and what DB is best for your application. I would be thinking about alternatives if I were you.

Comment: @PLane Databases are *designed* to hold lots of rows. It literally doesn't matter at all how large your data set is, there is *no* gain to splitting it into "smaller" data sets by dividing it into many tables, and quite a few disadvantages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with all answers to these sort of questions, it always depends somewhat on what your end result needs to be, but personally, I would always favour a single table over dynamically created tables - it makes for much simpler querying.  It also makes it somewhat simpler (I think) when you look at the database schema - many thousands of tables may make finding what you need when accessing the database directly a bit easier.

Additionally, if you find you need to extend your 'array' at some point with another field, it  means that there will be a single database table to alter, rather than many.

Answer (score 28):

Lots of rows in few tables. Making a new table for each new structure/record is absolutely incorrect and the very worst way to use a relational database.

In fact, almost any time your code is dynamically creating tables, you are doing something terribly, terribly wrong.

Comment: Agreed. Tables and row types ("columns") should always be fixed in code, unless you're coding another PHPMyAdmin. Haha :)

Comment: Would that still be correct if I had 1 million new row every week?

Comment: @Abatonime Yes, that would be *especially* correct. What's the alternative you're considering; one million new tables each week?

Comment: What about 100k entries per category per week, with not many common information with entries in different categories. around 100 new categories every week.

Comment: @SilverRingvee Yes, always and forever, lots of rows, few tables. It doesn't matter what kind of data you're storing or how much of it, I'll say it again: If you're dynamically creating tables, you're doing something wrong. 100k entries per week is *nothing*. Every dbms system ever built should be able to handle that without breaking a sweat.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like each array of data has a distinct schema.  Have you considered using a NoSQL database?  It will be much easier to work with, in my opinion.

If you must stick with MySQL, then you definitely want as few tables as possible.  Based on what you've presented, you could have one table with three columns -

```
array ;connects all the related records to the correct array
field ;the name of the field (array key)
value ;the actual value for that field
```

And, if you need multiple copies of the same array "type", add an instance column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of tables until the schema is normalized (has very little or no redundancy/duplication).  Don't increase the number of tables beyond that and be cautious about adding a new table for performance (modern databases, with a few exceptions, are faster than you think), or to deal with edge cases, such as duplication that occurs once per the life of the application, or for <1% of the rows.

It also would be easier to understand your question if we knew the domain of the question-- are these addresses, customers, books, or what?